# Ordenar posts Wordpress com Jquery ou meta_key e meta_value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Pretendo usar o código abaixo para ordenar e agrupar por seção posts do meu site Wordpress. Isso seria aplicado a Home Page e Categorias, onde cada post contaria com a classe css de acordo com sua seção (secao_1, secao_2 ou secao_3), sendo com a div pai desses elementos seria a id #content. A pergunta que faço é: até que ponto isso poderia prejudicar o desempenho do site em seu carregamento? Além disso, o ideal seria adicionar o código dentro da tag HEAD, para que o carregamento seja (do ponto de vista visual dos elementos) mais rápido? Outro detalhe, cada página teria 30 posts.

```
    var array = ['secao_1', 'secao_2', 'secao_3'];

    $.each(array,function(index,value){
       $('#content').append($('.'+value));
    });
```

Após fazer testes com Jquery, estou tentando chegar ao que quero através de meta_key e meta_value de campos criados com o plugin ACF, onde estou usando os Loops abaixo. O 1º e 2º loop buscam as meta_values secao_1 e secao_2, respectivamente. Já o 3º loop exibe os posts que não possuem qualquer seção.

Minha dúvida é saber se esse código pode ser melhorado. Além disso, as tags H2 acabam aparecendo na página 2 da categoria, mesmo que não haja posts de suas respectiva seções, como evitar isso?

```
<?php
global $query_string; parse_str( $query_string, $my_query_array ); 
$paged = ( isset( $my_query_array['paged'] ) && !empty( $my_query_array['paged'] ) ) ? $my_query_array['paged'] : 1;
$multi_type = array('post','post2');

// The Query
$query1 = new WP_Query(array(
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'post_type'         => $multi_type,
    'meta_key'          => 'sec_especial',
    'meta_value'        => 'secao_1',
    'category_name'     => 'featured'
));

// The Loop

echo '<h2>Seção 1</h2>';

    while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
        $query1->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );  
    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

/* The 2nd Query (without global var) */
$query2 = new WP_Query(array(
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'post_type'         => $multi_type,
    'meta_key'          => 'sec_especial',
    'meta_value'        => 'secao_2',
    'category_name'     => 'featured'
));

// The 2nd Loop

echo '<h2>Seção 2</h2>';

    while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
        $query2->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

/* The 3nd Query (without global var) */
$query3 = new WP_Query(array(
    'paged'        => $paged,
    'post_type'    => $multi_type,
    'category_name'=> 'featured',
    'meta_query'   => array(
        'relation'     => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'      => 'sec_especial',
            'value'    => false,
            'type'     => 'BOOLEAN'
        ),
        array(
            'key'      => 'sec_especial',
            'compare'  => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    )
));

// The 3nd Loop

echo '<h2>Seção 3</h2>';

    while ( $query3->have_posts() ) {
        $query3->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

    twentyfourteen_paging_nav();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito a sua pergunta, mas vamos lá:

> Até que ponto isso poderia prejudicar o desempenho do site em seu carregamento?

Ao meu ver, a diferença será mínima. Lembre-se que qualquer instrução que vai rodar no lado do cliente (no seu caso, `JavaScript`) vai ter um custo, por menor que ele seja. No caso de 30 posts, e da maneira como você construíu a instrução `jQuery`, não será tão custoso. Eu, particularmente, evitaria todo esse custo fazendo essa atribuição do lado do servidor. Se eu entendi bem, você quer dar uma classe pra `<div>` que contém o post de acordo com a sua categoria. O método [`in_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) verifica se um post (dentro de um loop), pertence a uma categoria. De maneira genérica:

```
if (have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post(); ?>

        <div class="content <?php if(in_category('minha_categoria')) echo 'minha_classe');?>">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Dessa maneira, você atribui a classe de acordo com a categoria do post diretamente dentro do loop, sem onerar o lado do cliente.

> Além disso, o ideal seria adicionar o código dentro da tag HEAD, para que o carregamento seja (do ponto de vista visual dos elementos) mais rápido?

O carregamento "rápido" envolve muita coisa, não só a presença do código no cabeçalho. O número de requisições é o que, basicamente, pode te causar problemas (além de, claro, código mal escrito). O WordPress tem um método para incluir scripts `.js` que é o [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). A seguinte linha, no seu `functions.php`

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

Inclui o script `example.js` que está no diretório `js`, que por sua vez está dentro da pasta do seu tema. Ele também seta a versão do script para a `1.0.0`, e incluí o script no footer. [Aqui uma discussão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105327/should-jquery-code-go-in-header-or-footer) sobre aonde devem ser colocados os scripts no seu código.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Caio. Eu tenho feito testes com o Jquery e buscado alternativas com meta_key e meta_value, criando campos personalizados com o plugin ACF. Nesses campos, teria as seções, aí quando eu fosse criar um post eu escolheria sua seção. Na página de categoria desse post, eu faria uma consulta por meta_key e meta_Value e agruparia tudo. Vou editar a pergunta e acrescentar o código.

Comment: @Rafael a sua edição alterou totalmente o teor da pergunta. Sugiro que a reverta e, se achar necessário, faça outra pergunta.